simple hybrid search in Qdrant
I am currently using Weaviate as my vector database. But I am hitting a memory limit on the compute node. On some research, i found out that weaviate HNSW index stays entirely on memory and I could not find any way to use disk with HNSW here.
Searching alternatives, I am now exploring Qdrant. Qdrant seems to natively support a on_disk flag which uses disk and mmaps, taking a hit on latency for scalability, which is okay for me. It also has attribute based pre-filtering, which i use often.
But one important thing I can not find is an simple equivalent of Weaviate's hybrid search. I personally like the implementation in Weaviate and have seen benefits on recall when using hybrid search.
Does anyone know what to do in this case?


On some research, i found out that weaviate HNSW index stays entirely on memory and I could not find any way to use disk with HNSW here.

This is not completely correct; Weaviate supports on disk (it's called the flat index) and even S3 offloading

https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/config-refs/schema/vector-index#flat-indexes
https://weaviate.io/developers/academy/py/vector_index/flat

Weaviate also supports a dynamic index, it automatically moves data between indecis

https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/config-refs/schema/vector-index#dynamic-indexes

You can even offload to S3 if you want

https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/configuration/tenant-offloading#offload-s3-module

Good luck building!
===
UPDATE
I misunderstood the question, the questioner clarified in the comments that they are looking for a disk solution if max memory is used while still using the HNSW index.
This is indeed possible, see vectorCacheMaxObjects  (it's in the vectorIndexConfig):  https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/config-refs/schema/vector-index#hnsw-index-parameters
By default, it's set to 1e12, so you could lower it.

You are correct. But the i am looking for HNSW index.
If you read closely, you will find that the dynamic index goes from Flat to HNSW when the size increases, which is absolutely counter intuitive. Its saying - use disk for smaller indexes and main memory for larger.

I see! Updated the answer, thanks for the clarification

This is great, somehow i did not go in depth over this part. This is exactly what i was looking for.
Please assist with one more thing, it says "A disk lookup for a vector is orders of magnitudes slower than memory lookup, so the disk cache should be used sparingly."
Do you have any resources that specifiy how much latency to expect in the case of using ssd / different types of disk when there's a cache miss?

If you're hitting memory limits with Weaviate’s HNSW index and need disk-based storage, Qdrant's on_disk flag is a good option. However, Qdrant does not natively support hybrid search like Weaviate.
To achieve similar functionality in Qdrant: Custom Hybrid Search, perform vector and keyword searches separately and then combine results manually. Or use additional tools: Integrate with Elasticsearch for keyword search and use Qdrant for vector search, then merge results.

Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems to defeat my whole purpose of looking for a "simpler" abstraction.

We completely support Hybrid Search at Qdrant. Actually there is an entire article about it and it's in the Hybrid Queries documentation page. Our version is vector-based and you need to use sparse and dense vectors. The Query API combines both searches sequently with a fusion algorithm.
There is a prefetch stage and the query is where the fusion algorithm combines results. This can lead to very high recall.


POST /collections/{collection_name}/points/query
{
    "prefetch": [
        {
            "query": { 
                "indices": [1, 42],    // <┐
                "values": [0.22, 0.8]  // <┴─sparse vector
             },
            "using": "sparse",
            "limit": 20
        },
        {
            "query": [0.01, 0.45, 0.67, ...], // <-- dense vector
            "using": "dense",
            "limit": 20
        }
    ],
    "query": { "fusion": "rrf" }, // <--- reciprocal rank fusion
    "limit": 10
}




Thats why i am asking for a simpler implementation. This one expects us to send a sparse vector to the databse just like we do for the dense vector. Getting a dense vector is easy with so many APIs available. But lets say i use SPLADE as Qdrant mentions many places, then getting the sparse vector is also an expensive task.
